# MIME-типы, зачем они нужны и что они делают?

Tags: android, mime

MIME-типы, зачем они нужны и что они делают?  зачем они используется в  запросах? (lib okHttp)? вот какие типы меня  интересует...

headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

header("User-Agent", getUserAgent())

RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8"), body); 
"application/octet-stream"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подробно лучше почитать на [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), хотя ответ в целом легко гуглится.

По сути mime-типы позволяют браузеру (а может и программисту на клиентской стороне, либо, как в вашем случае - android приложению) определить по заголовку, какого типа контент он получит. То есть браузер сразу знает, ждать ему изображение или простой текстовый файл.

Например, здесь, получив mime-тип контента, я в коде могу определить, что ответ сервера нужно интерпретировать как изображение.

```
connection.getContentType()
if(contentType.contains("image")){
    Bitmap image;
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
    result.obj = image;
}
```